How to read config kind file using shell script
I have a file names.txt
[Fruits]
Apple
Banana
Orange
[Vegetables]
Carrots
Spinach

I need to display the Apple, Banana and Oranges if the condition is met as Fruits. Similarly, if the condition is met for Vegetables, show Carrots and Spinach etc.
Can you please guide me how to achieve this using shell script.
I tried using while read line, but I could not get the desired way

If WHAT condition is met for Vegetables?  What are you comparing?

Ex: if the condition is met for Fruits, display 3 or 4 lines until you see a value which is embedded []. If the condition is met for Vegetables, read the lines until you find any value embedded []

"How" is too broad. There is no simple solution. There is no ini file parser in shell. You can either write your own, call an external program, or use maybe some open source parser. I would just call python and import configparser.

Pretty easy with awk -v what=Fruits '/^[[].*[]]$/ { if (match ($0, what)) found=1; else found=0; next} found' file Where file holds your text. The variable what holds the text between [...] you are attempting to match. Probably best called from a shell script where you set what and then make the call to awk.

I understand what the sentence_if the condition is met as Fruits_  means. As for your file: It looks at first glance, that it is in INI-format. If you can ensure that it is, consider using an INI-parser for the file instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It sounds like you want something like a JSON file, as you are querying data, not configuring a program.

The phrase "condition is met" still doesn't say anything.  Here's an example.  If you had said "I need to write a shell script where I can say 'show-me Fruits xxx.ini' and have it display the [Fruits] section", that's a very specific question that could be answered here easily.  Is that what you want?  And is awk allowed?

If all you're trying to do is print out the named section, then this might be a starting point for you:
#!/bin/sh

x="${1:-Fruits}"

doit=false
while read line; do
  case "$line" in
    "[$x]") doit=true; continue ;;
    "["*) doit=false; continue ;;
  esac
  $doit && printf "%s\n" "$line"
done

The initial doit=false protects you in the case that your first line is not a section head.
The way to "set" the condition for this script is obviously to include the section name as an option when you execute the script, and use your input data at stdin (i.e. redirecting input with <). If you would like something else, please edit your question, show us your work so far, and we'll figure out how to fix it.
